# External JavaScript function undefined, but exists

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 files, one HTML, one JavaScript.

JavaScript File (contacts.js):

```
function add_contact() {
    // Rest of Code here
}
```

HTML File:

```
<script src="/assets/js/contacts.js" type="javascript/text"></script>
```

I have a button that when it's clicked, it calls the 'add_contact' function:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="add_contact();">Save changes</button>
```

When the JavaScript code is the head of the HTML file, the function works fine. However, now it's part of the external file, it returns the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: add_contact is not defined

I feel a bit lost over this one, so any help would be fantastic!

Comment: Is your `add_contact` defined inside another block?

Comment: For a first type should be `text/javascript`

Comment: @JamesMcDonnell: Good catch on that!  Actually the `type` attribute can just be removed. :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat No, the function is the very first line in the .js file

Comment: Actually, @JamesMcDonnell that seems to have fixed it! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @JamesMcDonnell - if you could post it as an answer, I'd happily accept it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type should be `text/javascript` not `javascript/text`

Answer (score 3):

Change this block of markup:

```
<script src="/assets/js/contacts.js" type="javascript/text"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="/assets/js/contacts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```